# Does coproduct exist generally in the category of rings?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Here, rings always have an identity.
In the category of commutative rings, the coproduct of two commutative rings $A$ and $B$ is $A \otimes_Z B$.

My question is: does coproduct exist generally in the category of non-commutative rings? If yes, how to construct the product? If no, why?

I have tried that $A \oplus B$ equipped with componentwise operations is not the coproduct. I even consider in the category whose morphisms are not required to preserve identities and can not find the coproduct.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "product"? $A \times B$ is definitely the categorical product, in the sense that it has projections $A \times B \to A$ and $A \times B \to B$ inducing an isomorphism $\hom(R, A \times B) \cong \hom(R, A) \times \hom(R, B)$ for every ring $R$.

Comment: @S.C. I believe they meant “coproduct” since the tensor product is actually a coproduct, not a product, for commutative rings

Comment: If the question is about the tensor product of non-commutative rings, it still exists as $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$. The multiplication on the tensor product does not require commutativity. (More generally, if $A$, $B$ are algebras/monoids in a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$, then $A\otimes_{\mathcal{V}}B$ inherits a natural algebra structure itself. In your example $\mathcal{V}$ is the category of abelian groups with $\otimes_{\mathcal{V}} = \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}})$). That said, I'm not sure if that's your question

Comment: @Functor what did you make [of the wiki on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings#Limits_and_colimits)?

Comment: I have made a mistake about questions. The question should be about "coproduct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does exist. It is called the *free product*, and written $R*S$. A general element is a sum of products of elements of $R\cup S$. Since it is not required that elements commute, this cannot always be regrouped into a sum of products $rs$ with $r\in R$ and $s\in S$. Hence it is a lot larger than the tensor product.